# i want replace ~ to become URL backend, <img alt="" src="~/media/Banner/plane.JPG"> 404 not found

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

**1.** I got HTTP Request, response JSON, from backend localhost:3000 (value inputed using wysiwyg)

```json
{
"Description": "&lt;img alt=&quot;&quot; src=&quot;~/media/Banner/plane.JPG&quot; /&gt;1 test berita&lt;br /&gt;\r\n&amp;nbsp;"
}
```

**2.** in Angular html,

```html
<div [innerHTML]="data.description | safeHtml"></div>
```

(already decoded in component.ts)

**3.** In the browser,

```html
<div>
  <img alt="" src="~/media/Banner/plane.JPG">1 test berita<br>
  &nbsp;
</div>
```

**4.** The error is

```
GET http://localhost:4200/~/media/Banner/plane.JPG 404 (Not Found)
```

That error is because the URL was wrong. It should be using backend URL  `http://localhost:3000/media/Banner/plane.JPG`

I want to replace every `~` with `http://localhost:3000`.

```html
<img alt="" src="~/media/Banner/plane.JPG">
```

Comment: you can solve this by:
1. If the backend is your then remove the "~" sign from there only.
2. If the backend is **not** your then some id on image tag and handle src from javascript.

Answer (score 2):

**STEP 1**

Define `backend_URL` in the `environment.ts` file:

```js
export const environment = {
  backend_URL: 'http://localhost:3000/'
};
```

**STEP 2**

Import `environment` from `environment.ts` inside the component. Replace first character of the `data.src` with `environment.backend_URL`.

```js
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

...

public backend_URL = environment.backend_URL;

...

data.src = this.backend_url + data.src.substring(1);
```

**STEP 3**

Use `data.src` in the component.

```html
<img src="{{ data.src}}">
```

Comment: Not quite convinced the poster is able to do string replacement without some help. Think you need to add use of String#substr to get rid of the prefix

Comment: thank for helping me,
but the problem is,
when i got json response like `<img alt="" src="~/media/Banner/plane.JPG"><br><img alt="" src="~/media/Banner/train.JPG">` (double img).
and then i use pipe to replace(/~/g, env.baseAPIurl)
in html, `<div [innerHTML]="data.description | changetidetourl | safeHtml"></div>`

and it work.

Answer (score 1):

In ts file:

```js
// This could be from your environment file
const backendURL ="http://localhost:3000";

const obj = {
    "Description": "&lt;img alt=&quot;&quot; src=&quot;~/media/Banner/plane.JPG&quot; /&gt;1 test berita&lt;br /&gt;\r\n&amp;nbsp;"
};

obj['Description'] = obj['Description'].replaceAll('~', backendURL);

console.log(obj);
```

No need to change anything in the template.

Comment: Well you can also do this replacement in your `safeHtml` pipe

Comment: Glad it helped. Please Consider accepting the answer.

Comment: I was going to add pipe related answer but I was unaware about your code in pipe. Share safeHtml pipe code. Let's see if we can do it in one pipe. Instead of adding extra changetidetourl pipe

Comment: safeHTML `just transform(value: string) {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }` and changetildetourl `transform(url: any, args?: any): any {
    const replacement = url?.replace(/~/g, env.baseUrl);
    return replacement;
  }`

Comment: Why can't just transform safeHTML code to                                             
   `transform(value: string) {
 const value = value?.replace(/~/g, env.baseUrl) || '';
 return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
}`